# C struct is overwriting my array of pipe

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pipe

I must use an array of pipe to communicate between several processes, which is declared like this :

```
int myPipe[count][2];
```

I initialize it like this:

```
void init_tubes(int pipe_count, int pipe_array[pipe_count][2]){
    for (int i = 0; i < pipe_count; i++){
        if (pipe(pipe_array[i]) == -1){
            perror("Error on tube init");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

To communicate between the processes (forked processes), I am using this structure :

```
typedef struct {
    pid_t proc_id;
    int generated_value;
} pid_values;
```

Before I used this structure, information could be transmitted correctly.
But now if I set the `proc_id` value of my structure to something else, the last element of my array, myPipe[i][1] get overwritten by the value I set to proc_id.

I can still transmit information, it's just that the last file descriptor get overwritten, sometimes.

I declare my structure like this :

```
pid_values my_values = {0, 0};
```

And when I do `my_values.proc_id = getpid();` the last fd is overwritten by that pid. Why ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: There's not enough context to say anything. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line to help you find and fix problems like this. Tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) will also help.

Comment: As for things the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needs to show us, is the declaration, definition and *initialization* of `count`. The definition of `myPipe` (especially in relation to the initialization of `count`) and the code you use to initialize both `myPipe` and `my_values`. My guess, using my crystal ball, is that you initialize `count` *after* you defined the array `myPipe`, when `count` is uninitialized with an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) value, which then happens to be smaller than you think.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That was the issue. The size of my array was init to zero, then only after that it was set. But I declared the table before its size was set. This fixed it, thanks !